# Can `plt.style.context` from `matplotlib` be used as a `decorator` in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, plot, decorator

```
# Data
t = np.linspace(0,4*np.pi)
r = np.sin(t)

with plt.style.context("seaborn-white"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,2))
    ax.scatter(x=t, y=r, c="teal", marker="o", edgecolors="black", linewidths=1.5)
```

[image]

I want to do something like below.  Is this possible?

```
style = "seaborn-white"

# Fixed **args --> *args in response to @matusko comment

@style_decorator(style)
def subplot_wrapper(*args):
    return plt.subplots(*args)
```

### In response to @mgilson:

```
def style_decorator(style="seaborn-white"):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with plt.style.context(style):
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@style_decorator()
def subplots_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    return plt.subplots(*args, **kwargs)

fig, ax = subplots_wrapper(figsize=(5,2))
ax.scatter(x=t, y=r, c="teal", marker="o", edgecolors="black", linewidths=1.5)
```

Comment: you are using it incorrectly. Add `**kwargs` to your `subplots_wrapper`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you should be able to write that decorator pretty trivially<sup>1</sup>:

```
def style_decorator(style):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with plt.style.context(style):
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>At least ... As trivially as you can ever write a decorator that takes arguments.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer so quickly.  Sorry, I'm new to decorators and am a little confused on the usage.  I've updated the question to contain the error.

Comment: Your `subplots_wrapper` should probably accept `**kwargs` too.